# How to receive URL with "/" encoded

Tags: iis, request, uri, urlencode

My application relies on the URL for data; e.g.: /categories/parent_name/child_name

The URL is split on "/" to determine parent and child category names, which is used for database lookups. Some category names contain "/": /categories/parent_name/child_na/me So, it makes sense to escape "/" with "%2F" in URL: /categories/parent_name/child_na%2Fme

But when doing so, the server receives the request and converts "%2F" back to "/".

So, when I do a split on the URL, for the parts I undesirably get
  1) parent_name
  2) child_na
  3) me

and I want
  1) parent_name
  2) child_na/me

Any ideas on how to work around the issue? Is there any other way than dealing with the raw query string?

Comment: Have you tried double encoding (`%252f`) ?